# define value of column from table 1 as value in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables

table 1 contains

```
 id             site
  1              A1
  2              A2
  3              B1
  4              B2
```

table 2  contains

```
 nesite         fesite     
  A1              A2
  B1              A1
  A2              B2
```

**can I echoing table 2 as id from table 1?like,**

```
nesite         fesite     
  1              2
  3              1
  2              4
```

this far, I have tried some queries, nothing works. This my last shape of my model.

```
function site(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table2');
    $this->db->join('table1','table1.site = table2.nesite OR table1.site = table2.fesite');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join table1 twice times with table b using different columns like

```
select a1.id as nesite,
a2.id as fesite
from table2 b
join table1 a1 on (b.nesite = a1.site)
join table1 a2 on (b.fesite = a2.site)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cfce/5)

Active record query will be something like

```
$this->db->select('a1.id as nesite,a2.id as fesite',FALSE);
$this->db->from('table2 b');
$this->db->join('table1 a1','b.nesite = a1.site');
$this->db->join('table1 a2','b.fesite = a2.site');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result();
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried this before, but doesn't show anything, I think I miss something in "ON", :D